# Multi-site, different dashboard

Tags: multisite

I'm looking into using Wordpress Multi-site to have a three separate wordpress sites on one installation of Wordpress.

I have the Mulit-site set up and I can add sites but I have one admin log in to the multi site Dashboard showing all the sites.

Is it possible to have separate logins that login into the separate sites.

So if I have a cars website it would have it's own dashboard that the cars-admin could log into but wouldn't be able to see the multi-site dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Simply setup new users in the individual sites.

What you are using is what's called a "super admin" that has network level access.

Goto the dashboard for the site you would like to add user access and create a new user account to access that site only.

Comment: Note, too, that you can assign different permissions to users on different sites. So you can have user A have Editor access to Sites 1 and 2, Administrator on site 3, and nothing at all on Sites 4, 5, and 6.